# Unary, the destroyer of challenge ideas

Tags: discussion

Recently in the sandbox I've had [two challenge ideas](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?page=2&tab=active#comment16182_5579) pooh-poohed because it would be easily won by Unary, or one of its derivatives.

Now, I'm not saying exclude from the whole site because it can be use din ingenious ways, but what's the best way of excluding the language from challenges where it would easily win?

Furthermore, what are the Unary derivatives which can be listed in the passage describing Unary's exclusion?

Comment: +1 to counter that downvote. Perfectly valid question!

Comment: -1 because I strongly disagree with excluding any language from a challenge. Part of the fun of this site is using the best tool for the job. If it happens to be Unary, so be it.

Comment: @Jwosty I'm not disagreeing with you, but you may be interested in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's actually *trivial* for Unary to win a challenge, there's a good chance that part of the challenge spec is broken. There is not much you can do about ruling it out Unary specifically, because there will always be other languages with similar properties (like Pietu's [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage)). It doesn't really help to make an exhaustive list of Unary derivatives either. It's like saying "no golfing languages" for a standard code golf challenge because you want to give "normal" languages a chance to win. Excluding individual languages isn't any better than writing an unnecessarily language-specific challenge.

Instead, when someone tells you that a challenge is trivial in a certain language (this doesn't even have to be Unary), then you should a) consider whether that's even a problem (there are tons of challenges where Pyth is unbeatable - why shouldn't it be Unary for once?) and b) if it is a problem, then you might want to rethink your challenge/winning criterion instead. Ignoring the issue by excluding one language (family) is just treating the symptoms and ignoring an deeper problem. After all people inform you that a trivial solution exists instead of just waiting until the challenge is live to help you improve the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

One method of ruling out Unary-like derivatives is to impose a hard byte limit. It will unfortunately rule out some more exotic esolangs, but in the end it'll be up to you to decide what's reasonably long enough to allow most legitimate solutions.

As for Unary variants, there are:

- [Lenguage](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage)
- [Ellipsis](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ellipsis)
- [MGIFOS](http://esolangs.org/wiki/MGIFOS)
- [Ecstatic](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ecstatic)

But, as [Martin mentions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%c3%bcttner), ruling out each individually would not be a good way to go.

Comment: If you go the byte limit route, a simple one is requiring answers to contain the actual code, rather than a description of the code. Basically no Unary-like language will be able to fit anything meaningful into SE's 30k post length limit.

Comment: @Geobits That's a pretty good idea.